# I can't seem to figure out why my hamburger button wont work on my nav bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, django-bootstrap3

I was wondering if anyone knew why my hamburger button wont drop down on my navbar? I am not sure if I am not uploading the right JS files or what? I also have a scrollspy function in my JS file as well.

```
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional Theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'socialnet/css/style.css' %}">

  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-spy">

    <nav role = "navigation" class = "navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "{% url 'home' %}">Social Net</a>
        </div>
          <div class="navbar-spy">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav pull-right">
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href ="{% url 'posts:create' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Post</a></li>
                <li><a href ="{% url 'groups:all' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Groups</a></li>
                <li><a href ="{% url 'groups:create' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Create Group</a></li>
                <li><a href ="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Logout</a></li>
              {% else %}
                <li><a href ="{% url 'groups:all' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Groups</a></li>
                <li><a href ="{% url 'accounts:login' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href ="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Signup</a></li>
              {% endif %}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'socialnet/js/master.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `id="navbarCollapse"` on the `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">`

This is being referenced by the `<button>`'s `data-target="#navbarCollapse"`

```
<div class="navbar-spy">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href ="{% url 'posts:create' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Post</a></li>
            <li><a href ="{% url 'groups:all' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Groups</a></li>
            <li><a href ="{% url 'groups:create' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Create Group</a></li>
            <li><a href ="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Logout</a></li>
          {% else %}
            <li><a href ="{% url 'groups:all' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Groups</a></li>
            <li><a href ="{% url 'accounts:login' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href ="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Signup</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't notice that.